# How to make a list with RecyclerView with rows of the same width?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

My rows are not in the same size for some reason.I tried everything but it didn't work.By the way I'm very new to android.

I tried changing my row.xml but it did not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIv"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circulo_azul"
            android:src="@drawable/transferenciablue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageIv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageIv"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is the activitymain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyAdapter.java with onBindViewHolder:

```
package com.example.demoapp;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Model> models; // this array list creates a list of arrays which parameters define in my model class

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Model> models) {
        this.c = c;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,null); // this line inflate my row
        return new MyHolder(view); // this will return my view to holder class
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); // here i is position
        myHolder.mImaeView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getImg());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }
}
```

MyHolder class:

```
package com.example.demoapp;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImaeView;
    TextView mTitle;
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mImaeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageIv);
        this.mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make them appear proportional?Thanks

Comment: Change the layout to Linear layout and add weight to image view and tv as 2 and 8 and let their width be 0 dp u can still do with relative layout maybe u should try alignparentend true for tv along with current constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that you will write this type of code in BindViewHolder:

```
 @Override
public folder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name,parent,false);
    return new viewHolderClass(view);
}
```

some time width cannot appear properly because viewGroup cannot use

Comment: I will share my BindViewHolder but it's very similar to yours

Comment: in inflate method I think I have only `inflate(R.layout.row,null)`

Comment: parent is the object of parent view 
it in initial in oncreateViewHolder constructor mean ViewGroup object

Comment: I don't think I have the object of the parent view

Comment: I added myholder class

Comment: public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.row,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

Comment: this function replace to your oncreateViewHolder funaction

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_gravity="top"` to `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: I changed that but the rows stay the top.So I added a margin top to the recycler view and now it's in the center.But the problem is that the rows are in different sizes.